# IronRuby references conflict with System.Linq?

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, reference, ironruby

Using Visual Studio 2010, when I add the four IronRuby references to an existing project that uses Linq in several methods, the project won't compile due to not being able to find System.Linq all of a sudden. Does the IronRuby/.Net 4.0 Framework change the location of Linq or am I missing something?

Thanks,
Becky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the build for .NET 4.0?
The 3.0 build does have those overrides but they should be included in .NET 4.0.
http://ironruby.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=33305

Comment: RMagick won't work with IronRuby yet you can use the raw System.Drawing API just fine though. An effort has been started to port RMagick so it will work with the .NET stuff. 
http://github.com/sanxiyn/ironmagick
Feel free to help :)